# UITextfield is not showing the assigned NSString

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

UITextfield is showing null eventhough nsstring has value...

I've taken uitextfield in IB. Connection is correct in IB.

This is .h file

```
{
    IBOutlet UITextField    *dobTextField;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField    *dobTextField;
```

In .m file

```
@synthesize dobTextField;

-(void)displayDOB:(NSString*)str
{
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
    dobTextField.text = str;
}
```

In the log it is showing some value... but dobTextField is showing null...i tried

```
dobTextField.text = [NSString StringWithValue:@"%@", str];
```

but no use....

Please help me out guys.

Comment: if i use ARC, what is the solution for that...

Answer (score 1):

Try doing...

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.dobTextField);
```

is it nil? (it shouldn't be)

Sounds like you possibly haven't connected up the outlet in IB.

**EDIT**

Hmm... second thoughts I think you're confusing things.

1. Remove the ivar from the .h file. Just use the @property.

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *dobTextField;
   ```
2. Remove the @synthesize from the .m file.
3. In displayDOB function use this...

   ```
   self.dobTextField.text = str;
   ```

This will ensure that everything is referring to the same thing and also uses best practise methods when it comes to properties.

Comment: Follow my steps then. Looks like you're mixing up the ivar and the property,

Comment: still not working... did i miss something... r we need to allocate it or what?

Comment: If you've followed the steps then you might find you need to connect up again in IB. Next to the property should be a small filled in circle (in the margin). If this isn't filled in then it isn't connected.

Comment: The ivar and the property are connected by the synthesize statement since they have the same name.

Comment: Yes, but this is not recommended practise. Apple suggests not to use the ivar at all. That is all I was recommending.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - However, if you remove the `@synthesize` under the latest LLVM versions, the property will be connected to an ivar that has an underscore prefix, not the one with the exact same name. That's a fairly subtle thing that can trip you up here.

Comment: I always go for property with no ivar now. Removes confusion and redundancy. property plus ivar plus synthesize = "Create a property with getter and setter, then synthesize an ivar for it also with the same name as the property, but now here is the ivar anyway just in case you forgot." just seems like complicating things too much.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you have not set your outlet of UITextField in xib

Check that in your interface builder

Also,
change this line

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField    *dobTextField;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField    *dobTextField;
```

Also, change this line

```
dobTextField.text = str;
```

to

```
self.dobTextField.text = str;
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Are you allocating your class properly?

Comment: First suggest is correct. The second is to retain the text field? The text field doesn't need to be retained, it's already retained by the view itself. Without ARC it could be a weak property as well.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Its highly recommended that if you are doing property of any object, it should be accessed with self.objectName

Comment: No way is recommended, they're just different ways to do it and you should use the correct way according to the situation. In this case he doesn't need to retain the text field, so he could safely declare it weak, or don't use the accessor.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Quite strange, you have such good reputation and you say not to use self.objectname :)

Comment: Also, SA has not stated in question whether he uses ARC or not, so I just go with what code actually pasted. Also, in real terms making retain is to increase reference count of object by 1. And adding more info to it, retain is been replaced by strong. I hope you are aware about this.. :)

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Let me repeat this again for you, check when SA user said about he uses ARC and my answer time. Let me explain more one thing, there is no use to do property for IBOutlets, so whatever you said is wrong. So, better from next time check date and time before leaving any comment, this might save anybody useful time.. :)

Comment: He synthesized the property so he generated the accessor, and there isn't any reason to use self.dobTextField; I suggest to give a good reason when you say that something is recommended over something else. Also, in ARC retain stands for strong. He is using ARC yes, to be precise he said this 2 hours  ago and your "Also, SA has not stated in question whether he uses ARC or not" was 1 hour ago, but I am not so mean to accuse you for this. With or without ARC, you are still not providing a valid reason for using self.dobTextField instead of dobTextField.

Comment: If you are not using ARC, @property (nonatomic, retain)  is valid!

Comment: That's what I said, but why self.dobTextField vs dobTextField?

Comment: If you use property, you should always attach self.objectname. This is what I only mean

Comment: Without wasting much of my time, suggest you to refer Apple reference documents and check that. OR else you can ask this as question in SO, I will be first one to answer you :)

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Downvote, why? Upper answer edited answer and also it matched same, then why downvote me

Comment: Because it's wrong. That's like if you say to replace int a=5; with int a=0x5; You also haven't explained the reason (thing that should be always done in any answer) for using that syntax, so the downvote came natural.